# load data infile does not work with quotes around datetime

Tags: mysql

I have trouble loading a file with supposedly valid datetime format. For example a row in the loaded file looks like:
4,0,'2012-08-09 22:34:28','2012-08-09 22:34:28'

The same format works with insert statements. Is this not a valid datetime format when loading? Do we have to specify a default format in any case? Should I cast it?

Comment: Ahh! never mind. When loading a file, the datetime does not expect quotes around it. The row thus should be  4,0,2012-08-09 22:34:28, 2012-08-09 22:34:28

Answer (score 0):

Answered by OP:

> Ahh! never mind. When loading a file, the datetime does not expect quotes around it. The row thus should be 4,0,2012-08-09 22:34:28, 2012-08-09 22:34:28

(Removing from "Unanswered")

Answer (score 0):

In your `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement add

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "'"
```

See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) for the syntax:

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number LINES]
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]
```